# Calculate Session duration / length

Tags: session

Salesforce provides login history, but not log-out history or session timeout history... This has me stumped on how to calculate user session length!

Is there a way to calculate when the user logged in, and how long the user was logged in for?

I'm looking for functionally similar to [ChronSights Handle Time Metrics](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001gZ0hEAE), but hoping to find a free solution either in the Appexchange or natively within Salesforce

Couple other promising apps found:

[Time Track](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001qKTYEA2)

MaxmTrack: Third link found in the comments due to link limitation based on reputation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Functionally similar to: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001gZ0hEAE

But hoping to find a free solution either in the Appexchange or natively within Salesforce.

Comment: MaxmTrack: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000007eLjzEAE

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the session time?

Comment: @AlexTennant, I'm trying to create an agent performance report. By default, users are timed out after X minutes, but since Salesfoce doesn't provide log out history, I can't compute exact working hours.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?